# Trying to find a set of numbers

Tags: vba, excel, find

I’m trying to develop a small VBA program (not a formula) to help find the number 15 in a set of numbers. I’m using Excel 2010, Windows 7 software. I'm learning VBA but have a long way to go and sure would appreciate any help to get me started on this one.

Thanks
Mike

I need the program to find any pairs of numbers that has a 15 in the last number (eg. 8-15 or 1-15 or 12-15) in the specific following cells: B30,E30,H30,K30,N30 (could be more than one set of numbers with a 15 in the range of numbers). These cells are just examples, the list is a long one but I can enter extra cells afterwards).

If there are NO positive result end the program.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. We're more than happy to help you figure out why the code you've written to attempt to do this yourself isn't working.

Comment: I have a sample code here that will loop through a range of cells to to find "A1" play with the code, edit the ranges and change the one line from `if c="A1" then` to  `If c Like "*15" Then`
http://www.xlorate.com/excel-vba-loops.html#Add%20Range%20to%20Range

Comment: Thanks for the link, it look great @Davesexcel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Loop through some pre-determined range (set by `SearchRange`)
2. See if `15` is the last 2 characters in `SearchCell` using `Right`
3. If `TRUE` (I.E. `15` is in the last 2 characters of string) then color cell red
4. If `FALSE` do nothing

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Found()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim SearchRange As Range, SearchCell
Set SearchRange = ws.Range("B30,E30,H30,K30,N30")

For Each SearchCell In SearchRange
    If Right(SearchCell, 2) = 15 Then SearchCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
Next SearchCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi I just tried your code and it works great. Thank-you so much for your help @urdearboy